# Priestly blessing grammar - יאר

Tags: grammar-dikduk, parshat-nasso

In the Priestly blessing (במדבר ו:כד-כה)

... יברכך ה' וישמרך.יאר ה', פניו אליך, ויחנך.. What is the שורש and בינין of the word יאר?

Thanks

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100120/759

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The root of יָאֵר is אור. The binyan is הפעיל (and נחי ע"ו). The form יָאֵר instead of יָאִיר is due to [jussive mood](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/48._Shortening_and_Lengthening_of_the_Imperfect_and_Imperative._The_Jussive_and_Cohortative) ("may he shine" instead of "he will shine"). The word וְיָשֵׂם in the next verse is conjugated the same way. The conjugation of the root אור is irregular for נחי ע"ו in many cases, but this is not one of them.