# Priestly blessing grammar - וישם

Tags: grammar-dikduk, birchas-kohanim

In the Priestly blessing (במדבר ו:כד-כה), for the word וישם, is the the root שים or is the root ישם?

ישם -'Implement', https://pealim.com/dict/864-leyasem
שים - 'Put', https://www.pealim.com/dict/45-lasim/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not personally familiar with the root ישׂמ in biblical Hebrew (though maybe it exists). This is שׂימ (or equivalently שׂומ or שׂמ), to put or give. Roots with ו (or י or nothing) as the second of their three letters will look like this in [the jussive](//en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/48), q.v.